# Total max value with for multiple dependent jQuery-UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, range, uislider

I'm trying to make a skills-maker-like interface with 4 jQuery-UI sliders (first time I use this UI library).

Sliders are limited to a total amount (here 10) and I'm trying to stop the increase slide when this limit is reached.
I readed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293710/jquery-slider-how-do-i-make-a-group-of-sliders-having-max-value-depending-on-an), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375536/updating-max-value-of-jquery-slider-from-input-field) but the result is not very usable. The user needs to much time understand how the slider group works. That's why I test to don't change the slider "size" but just bloc the slider increase.
I success to stop the slider. But the linked number continue increseasing.

Here my attempt: **http://jsfiddle.net/PXEG2/**

I tried that :

```
function total(){
    var value = parseInt($('#item1').val()) + parseInt($('#item2').val()) + parseInt($('#item3').val()) + parseInt($('#item4').val());
    if(value > 10){
        $('.slider').slider({max: $(this).slider(max)});
    }
}
```

May be, I don't use the good way ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combined total for multiple jQuery-UI Sliders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486371/combined-total-for-multiple-jquery-ui-sliders)